# Union 2 tables sql, only shows first query

Tags: php, sql-server, join, union

I am trying to join 2 queries using UNIÓN, but it only shows me the result of the first Query, the following code works in SQLServer & phpMyAdmin but not when executing in a PHP script, I would also like to try with JOIN but it does not work for me. (I am using functions that receive 2 parameters: category, id user. the first query hosts "tasks performed" by the user and the second query returns "pending tasks". The first query has fewer columns so fill it with NULLs)

```
            (SELECT ca.*, pem.orden  FROM Escolares.ftCardex('7', '3395') AS ca, Escolares.plan_estudios_materia AS pem WHERE pem.idmateria=ca.idMateria AND pem.idplan_estudios=ca.idPlanDeEstudios )
             UNION ALL
            (SELECT NULL, NULL, idMateria, NULL, Materia,
             NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
             NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
            NULL, NULL
               FROM Escolares.ftMateriasPorCursar('7', '3395'))
            ORDER BY orden
```

The results are like these:

[image: From ID 17 the second Query is separated from the first one.]

---

## Solved

I think the error was the way PHP executes the Query, the problem was similar to:
[PDO UNION with ? not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933485/pdo-union-with-not-working)

Comment: You should start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been available now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins For the question at hand we need some details to work with. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: First thing I'd do is get rid of the * and use the explicit column names instead.  Then get rid of the parenthesis around each SELECT statement.  They aren't needed. And as Sean said, change the join style.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: @Lamu Please do not inline links inappropriately. See my comment above re using text whenever possible. This image or a link to it should not be in this post without text for all its content that can be expressed by text. Either replace a link to an image with text by its text plus--if still supplementally useful--the image or, much better, comment to tell the poster to do it.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. (That includes a clear specification & output & desired output. "it does not work for me" tells us nothing.) Also: Part of justifying "minimal" is finding a working example for maximal partial functionality. Show a program that calculates what you expect it to as it goes through (sub)expressions--including that arguments passed to each function/operator meet its requirements--by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. Add code giving a problem. Ask about the (small) difference between the examples. (Basic debugging.)

Comment: Hi. Please don't edit titles to be [SOLVED], just click to accept an answer. If relevant to say more just edit the body of your question. See [help] links re accepting answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO UNION with ? not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933485/pdo-union-with-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replacing "*" fields with numbers "one", "two", etc. Listing them out will ensure that your fields line up between queries:

```
 SELECT ca.[one]
       ,ca.[two]
       ,ca.idMateria
       ,ca.[three]
       ,ca.[Materia]
       ,ca.[five]
       ,ca.[six]
       ,ca.[seven]
       ,ca.[eight]
       ,ca.[nine]
       ,ca.[ten]
       ,ca.[eleven]
       ,ca.[twelve]
       ,ca.[thirteen]
       ,ca.[fourteen]
       ,ca.[fifteen]
       ,ca.[sixteen]
       ,ca.[seventeen]
       ,ca.[eighteen]
       ,ca.[nineteen]
       ,ca.[twenty]
       ,pem.orden
 FROM   Escolares.ftCardex('7', '3395') AS ca
        JOIN Escolares.plan_estudios_materia AS pem ON pem.idmateria = ca.idMateria
                                                       AND pem.idplan_estudios = ca.idPlanDeEstudios
 UNION ALL
 SELECT [one] = NULL
       ,NULL
       ,idMateria
       ,NULL
       ,Materia
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
 FROM   Escolares.ftMateriasPorCursar('7', '3395')
 ORDER BY orden;
```

Comment: I think the error was the way PHP executes the Query, the problem was similar to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933485/pdo-union-with-not-working